# Identify this type of geranium

Tags: identification, geraniums

We've recently bought this geranium, but I can't for the life of me find its type. Does anyone know? (Google Lens says it's a moth orchid...)

Also - we worry a bit about the dried up leaves. The plant is watered every day and the florist assured us it's a plant that thrives best outside in a pot.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is Geranium maderense, a tender, perennial geranium native to Madeira. It forms this stout trunk and the leaves droop downwards; the leaves are often few and may look tatty when it's in flower. It's usually kept in a pot because it is tender, and therefore easier to move under shelter if you want to over winter it in colder countries. It might benefit from a larger pot, but don't do that while it's still in flower. The leaves tend to do better in shadier situations - dappled sun is good. If yours has been receiving full sun, that might account for the number of withered leaves, but so long as you're watering it often enough and allowing it to drain freely, it shouldn't die, despite the rather tatty appearance of the foliage. If you want to keep it for next year, after its finished flowering, turn it out of its pot to see if it needs a larger one, and pot on if necessary. https://www.thompson-morgan.com/p/geranium-maderense/t16824TM